# embedded youtube video in App plays black screen

Tags: android, ios, iframe, youtube

Platform I'm using to build app is app makr. The section I am trying to embed in is custom content.  Simulator plays vid but live version is audio only. Black screen. Using standard embed code iframe. And tried other codes. No luck. Any advice ?

Code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/P0M6Jjh5Rdw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Mind sharing what else you tried?

Comment: I tried the option on youtube that says "Use Old Embed Code" and a snipped I found on google, which I currently can not find if my life depended on it.. SMH

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this:
https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView

And see my answer on how to add the YouTubeVideo to a UIView:
[Open YouTube Video in a UIView using LBYouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925848/open-youtube-video-in-a-uiview-using-lbyoutube/20928150#20928150)